# static sidebar to dynamic sidebar to use the fullwidth

Tags: sidebar

i have the decent theme {http://demo.themeshift.com/decente/} and i want to have the same layout like in the demo with NO homepage- sidebar.
how can i display the sidebar an use the fullwith page?
look at my page {[http://www.wohnträume-soltau.de](http://www.wohntr%C3%A4ume-soltau.de)}
thanks a lot guys
{">

```
// Hook to add content before widgets in sidebar
do_action( 'frameshift_sidebar_widgets_before' );

if( is_front_page() && is_active_sidebar( 'home' ) ) {

    if( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-home' ) ) {
            dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-home' );
        } elseif( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) {
            dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' );
        } else { ?>

        <div class="widget no-widget">

            <div class="widget-inner">

                <h4 class="title title-widget"><?php _e('Widget Area', 'frameshift'); ?></h4>

                <?php echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'This is a widget area. Please drag and drop your preferred widgets to the area %s', 'frameshift' ), '<strong>' . __( 'General Sidebar', 'frameshift' ) . '</strong> ' . __( 'or', 'frameshift' ) . ' <strong>' . __( 'Home Page Sidebar', 'frameshift' ) . '</strong>' ) . ' &rarr; <a href="' . home_url() . '/wp-admin/widgets.php">' . __( 'Edit Widgets', 'frameshift' ) . '</a></p>' . "\n"; ?>

            </div><!-- widget-inner -->

        </div><!-- .widget --><?php

    }

} elseif( ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_page_template( 'page-tpl-blog.php' ) ) && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-archive' ) ) {

    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-archive' );

} elseif( is_single() && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-post' ) ) {

    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-post' );

} elseif( is_page() && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-page' ) && ! is_page_template( 'page-tpl-blog.php' ) ) {

    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-page' );

} elseif( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) {

    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' );

}

// Hook to add content after widgets in sidebar
do_action( 'frameshift_sidebar_widgets_after' ); ?>
```